# How to pas props to MUI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I tried changing the mui datepicker to a different format, but it always fails.
this code work for me

```
const Step2 = ({handlechange,value: {startTime}}) =>
{
 return(
  <TextField
  fullWidth
  required
  color="success"
  size="small"
  label="Start Time"
  name='startTime'
  type="datetime-local"
  value={startTime || '2022-06-24T10:30' }
  InputLabelProps={{
   shrink: true,
  }}
  margin="normal"
  onChange={handlechange}
/>
 )
}
export default Step2
```

but how to implement to MUI Datetime picker to this

```
const Step2 = ({handlechange,value: {startTime}}) =>
{
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(new Date());
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DateTimePicker
        renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
        label="DateTimePicker"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}/>
    </LocalizationProvider>)
}
export default Step2
```

Comment: Have u tried `inputFormat="MMM D, YYYY"` ? (I'm using a different dateAdapter, but it should work)

Comment: i mean is pass startTime to value and handleChange to on change,